# VSC no me reconoce Flet

Tags: python, vscode, flet

Al parecer VSC no me reconoce Flet, y tengo instalado Flet usando el "pip install flet" y hasta lo actualice con "--upgrade".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Comprueba que `flet` esté instalado en la misma instalación de Python que esté cogiendo Visual Code. Si haces click abajo a la derecha donde dice la versión de Python (3.12.2 64-bit) verás la lista de instalaciones de Python disponibles. Asegúrate de elegir la misma en la que instalaste `flet`.